# MSBuild Compilation Error Weirdness

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm getting an error compiling a VB .NET project using the MSBuild command line. Running from devenv works perfectly fine:

```
error BC30518: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Invoke' can be called with these arguments:
```

Line in question:

```
  Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() InteractionManager.Current.DisplayException((DirectCast(e.ExceptionObject, Exception))))
```

Why is MSBuild balking at this when DevEnv/Visual Studio is not? And why is this a problem at all? It looks fine to me.... The ONLY thing I see interesting about this line is that Invoke takes a Delegate class object (not a strongly typed delegate)...so in C#, I wouldn't be able to use a lambda expression where I am now in VB .NET (I'd need to do something like new Action(() => ...)

Comment: Usual thing, turn error logging up to verbose and see what the command line etc actually being invoked is. Might discover you're not invoking the VB compiler of the version you think you are, or something.

Comment: Running c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Vbc.exe as expected

Comment: I've also noticed A LOT of my projects are now asking for WindowsBase and PresentationCore references when the sln invoked through MSBuild...but not when running under devenv. Adding the references seems to have resolved that inexplicable problem though...

Comment: You could try turning up the verbosity in VS as well (`Tools | Options | Project and Solutions | Build and Run`) and comparing the `vbc` command line that VS is executing against that that MSBuild is running. And from the other angle, you could go down to the command line and invoke `vbc` yourself on the minimal program exhibiting the problem. Build problems are always a pain to debug!

Comment: Yeah...I was going to try to migrate from devenv in our TFS team build to msbuild, but it seems like msbuild just isn't up to the task of use in a production build environment. Back to devenv I think, until someday perhaps msbuild becomes a mature fully baked solution.

Comment: (but judging from the forums, these problems have existing since 2005 and haven't been resolved yet)

Comment: Visual Studio uses MSBuild, so whatever your trying to do directly with MSBuild is possible. The problem is trying to determine how Visual Studio is using MSBuild. Its probably some missing command line argument.

Comment: Visual Studio does not use msbuild directly, like the msbuild command line does. They function quite differently.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are mixing .NET versions.

`System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher` has a single argument overload of the `Invoke` method in .NET 4.5.  In .NET 4.0 or older, all available overloads take two or more arguments which rules then out and gives you the error message you see.

I therefore assume that the `devenv` you are executing is a VS2012 beta whereas the `msbuild` is something more conventional.

You should be able to resolve the discrepancy by adjusting your `Path` environment variable.

Comment: @JeffN825 - Look closely at your `Imports` directives.  If you are (very) sure that .NET 4.5 is not installed anywhere on your machine, then the single-argument `Invoke` is an extension method and you need to figure out what code contributed it into this context.